# inquiries for writing continuous wavelet transform codes manually

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, wavelet

I want to write continuous wavelet transform  codes manually by matlab. And I want to use complex morlet function. Here are some background:
Continuous wavelet transform definition: $C(S,T;f(t),\psi (t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{S}}\int_{S}^{b}f(t)\psi^{\ast }(\frac{t-T}{S})$
S is scale vector.for example `1:60;`$T$ is time slid. 
And $\psi(t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi f_{b}}}e^{2\pi f_{c} t}e^{\frac{-t^{2}}{f_{b}}}$

```
psi = ((pi*fb)^(-0.5)).*exp(2*1i*pi*fc.*t).*exp(-t.^2/fb); % for example fb=15;fc=1;
```

my discrete signal has $N$ points. discrete version of that integral for the first element in the scale vector  is:  `for s(i)`
$C_{T}(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(n)\psi^{*}(\frac{T-n}{S})$ this must calculate for all scales,`1:60;`
at the end it must return me a complex matrix with $N\times S$ size.
I am confused about wrting this codes. Anyone can help?
P.S I don't want to uses matlab function `conv2` to calculate that convolution.
Thanks in advance.
 here is my first attempt, but it's not working at all.

```
%% user CWT
clear all
N=300;                %sample point numbers
t=linspace(0,30,N);
%% signal
x=5*sin(2*pi*0.5*t);  % signal with freq of 0.5 HZ
%% cwt
    fc=1;fb=15;
% psi=((pi*fb)^(-0.5)).*exp(2*1i*pi*fc.*...
%     t).*exp(-t.^2/fb);
%% convolution Psi([N-n]/S)*x(n) so we calculate convolution(psi(n/s),x(n))
    for s=1:60   %scale vector s=[1:1:60]
for i = 1:N      % number of discrete times
       for k = 1:i 
               if ((i-k+1)<N+1) && (k <N+1)
                PSI = ((pi*fb)^(-0.5)).*exp(2*1i*pi*fc.*...
       (t/s)).*exp(-(t/s).^2/fb);   
                        c(i,s) = c(i)+ x(k)*PSI(i-k+1);
                end
       end
end
    end
```

Comment: References to fast CWT implementations are given in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37528/implementing-continuous-wavelet-transform/37530#37530

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Python code that I use for CWT. You'll need a short 16bit mono 44.1Khz `test.wav` soundfile as input.

In order to compute the CWT, we need to compute the convolution between the input `x[n]` and the morlet wavelet. An efficient way to do this is to do `ifft(x_ft * morlet_ft)`
( I understand this as $f * g(t) =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(w) \hat{g}(w) e^{i t w} d w$ : it is more efficient to do a **multiplication** of the fourier transforms and THEN to do an inverse fourier transform, than to compute a convolution directly)

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy

# read the file                              
(sr, samples) = read('test.wav')    
x = (np.float32(samples)/((2 ** 15)-1))
N = len(x)
x_fft = np.fft.fft(x)

# scales
J = 200    
scales = np.asarray([2**(i * 0.1) for i in range(J)])

# pre-compute the Fourier transform of the Morlet wavelet 
morletft = np.zeros((J, N))
for i in range(J):
  morletft[i][:N/2] = sqrt(2 * pi * scales[i]) * exp(-(scales[i] * 2 * pi * scipy.array(range(N/2)) / N - 2)**2 / 2.0)

# compute the CWT 
X = empty((J, N), dtype=complex128)
for i in range(J):
  X[i] = np.fft.ifft(x_fft * morletft[i])

# plot
plt.imshow(abs(X[:,scipy.arange(0,N,100)]), interpolation='none', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Here is the scalogram plot that this code gives :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, I know `ifft` convolution is efficient and the computational burden is lower, but do you have any idea how can I get the convolution with normal definition? tnx much @basj

Comment: If `x[n]` is defined for `n=0,1,2,..N-1` you can use
`cwt[a,b]=sum(x*psi[(here scaled and shifted)])` , doesn't it work ? ;)